# fastify.plugin создать из функции плагин

Tags: node.js, fastify

Не получается из небольшой функции сделать плагин для fastify. Есть документация по этому поводу но по ней получается только оборачивать npm пакеты как плагин для fastify.

Документация : https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Plugins.md

функция которую я хочу подключить как плагин ( функция на скорую руку лишь бы выполняла то что нужно =) )

```js
module.exports = (pin) => {
    let one = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
    let two = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
    let tree = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
    let mask_pin = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));
    let mask = "";
    switch (mask_pin) {
        case 0: mask = "xzxc"; break;
        case 1: mask = "zxcx"; break;
        case 2: mask = "zxxc"; break;
    }

    return mask
    .replace(/[z]/g, one)
    .replace(/[x]/g, two)
    .replace(/[c]/g, tree);
}
```

планируется ее вызывать как то так `fastify.pin();`

когда оборачиваю функцию как npm пакеты то она выполняется 1 раз при запуске приложения и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать из функции плагин. Код прилагаю

`epin.js`

```js
const fp = require('fastify-plugin');

const epin = function (pin) {  // Функция которая будет вызываться
    let one = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
    let two = (9 - Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9)))
    let tree = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
    let mask_pin = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(3));
    let mask = "";
    switch (mask_pin) {
        case 0: mask = "xzxc"; break;
        case 1: mask = "zxcx"; break;
        case 2: mask = "zxxc"; break;
    }

    return mask
        .replace(/[z]/g, one)
        .replace(/[x]/g, two)
        .replace(/[c]/g, tree);
}

const fastify_epin = (fastify, options, next) => {
    let transporter = null;

    try {
        transporter = epin;
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err)
    }

    fastify
        .decorate('epin', transporter)
        .addHook('onClose', close)
    next()
}

const close = (fastify, done) => {
    fastify.epin.close(done)
}

module.exports = fp(fastify_epin, {
    fastify: '>=2.0.0',
    name: 'fastify-epin'
})
```